# Calling a function in the views located in settings.py

Tags: django, django-views

Is this possible to call a function located in `settings.py`?

```
def myfn():
   return "hello world"
```

view:

```
from django.conf import settings
def my_view(request)
    print(settings.MYFN())
```

Comment: `settings.myfn()`…?

Comment: @deceze Hellom, I have tried that but I get `settings` object has no attribute myfn

Comment: Never tried this, and I really have to ask what the purpose would be .. pretty sure you're trying to solve a problem in the wrong way here.

Comment: @urbanespaceman I am defining a directory. Where should it be?

Comment: i suggest you creating `utils.py` file (as convention / recommended way ..) and put your project-level functions there.

Comment: `utils.py` tends to end up as a bit of a nasty "catch-all" ;)

Comment: @Andd I'd suggest using an environment var to set a directory, then just loading that in `settings.py`. That's the normal way of handling this sort of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only capitalised symbols are accessible via `django.conf.settings`, so if you `def MYFN`, it's accessible via `settings.MYFN`.